# Windows applications with Unity+ARToolKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

My question is can you built Windows (.exe) applications using ARToolKit in Unity? I've been working with Vuforia only to find out it supports mobile OS's and Win 10, but in editor on Win 8 it works just fine...

By the way has anybody tried connecting ARToolKit with MiddleVR, which I use for head and hand tracking, if so please share some thoughts about it.

I'm using NVisor ST50 + Inertia Cube 4, just in case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to build Windows stand alone applications using Unity and ARToolKit. 
I cannot say anything in regards to your other question, sorry.